# How to receive Unicode String from database by Java

Tags: java, sql, database, unicode

I'm Vietnamese, I used to use some Unicode character ex 'Việt Nam', â, ẵ, ấ, ị, đ, Đ, Ệ, Ố, ư..., I'm having a exercise relate with insert/receive data from database, I'm using Java. I can not receive data from database without many error with there character. Who can help me ?

Comment: I think there are lot of qualified people here who can help you. But a stack trace (if applicable) and a code snippet would go a long way in helping them help you. Also the type and version of the database is important.

Comment: What database are you using?  What character encoding do you want to use (Unicode is a family of character encodings, which one)?

Comment: Make sure the database column type is `nvarchar` (or whatever may be appropriate for the particular engine). There may be some magical "stuffing" occurring which mangles the input to "ASCII" -- again, depends on engine (and adapter).

Comment: nothing complicated, you have to correctly set 1/ Charset 2/ Collation for whole database or dbTable(s) only

Comment: I'm using Java SE with Microsoft Office Access. Who can help me

Answer (score 0):

It whould be better to understand your problem with the `exact error code`. But as I underestand you, your problem is that you have something in database ( and it's okthere ) but when you want to read and show it, you face with some problems. With these background I think:

- you have to use utf-8 to store and read data.
- your application have to support your locale. ( for instance as I know JDK doesn't support fa_IR locale, so it may be your problem)
- But as there are lots of vietnamians java application, your problem should belongs to your **DAL**.

Provide complete error and ensure that your data is stored correctly in your database.

Comment: I'm using Java SE with Microsoft Office Access.

Answer (score 0):

Try Java 7 if you want to use Access database.

Otherwise, use a different DBMS that Java currently supports queries or updates with Unicode characters.

[Java Programming with Vietnamese](http://vietunicode.sourceforge.net/howto/java/)